# PEAR error + Open Server and Opencart project

Tags: php, pear

I have a project based on Opencart 3+ version on my OpenServer.
Then i try to load my project i have some errors.

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 5 bytes in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\admin\index.php on line 46

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 22 bytes in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\admin\index.php on line 46

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 9 bytes in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\admin\index.php on line 46

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 9 bytes in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\admin\index.php on line 46

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 29 bytes in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\admin\index.php on line 46
Warning: ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\system\library\session.php on line 7
Warning: ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\system\library\session.php on line 8
Warning: session_set_cookie_params(): Cannot change session cookie parameters when headers already sent in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\system\library\session.php on line 10
Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\system\library\session.php on line 11
Notice: Undefined index: filename in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\admin\index.php on line 123
Notice: Error: Could not load language ! in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\system\library\language.php on line 43
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\admin\index.php:46) in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\system\library\currency.php on line 52
Warning: unlink(c:/OpenServer/domains/depotop/system/cache/cache_c21f969b5f03d33d43e04f8f136e7682_7f24d9fc4140045241b3f97bcf36bf03): No such file or directory in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\vendor\pear\cache_lite\Cache\Lite.php on line 608
Warning: include_once(PEAR.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\vendor\pear\cache_lite\Cache\Lite.php on line 567
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'PEAR.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\vendor/pear/cache_lite;.') in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\vendor\pear\cache_lite\Cache\Lite.php on line 567
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PEAR' not found in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\vendor\pear\cache_lite\Cache\Lite.php:568 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\vendor\pear\cache_lite\Cache\Lite.php(609): Cache_Lite->raiseError() 
#1 C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\vendor\pear\cache_lite\Cache\Lite.php(459): Cache_Lite->_unlink() 
#2 C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\admin\model\localisation\currency.php(170): Cache_Lite->remove() 
#3 C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\admin\controller\common\login.php(89): ModelLocalisationCurrency->updateCurrencies() 
#4 C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\system\engine\front.php(42): ControllerCommonLogin->index() 
#5 C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\system\engine\front.php(29): Front->execute() 
#6 C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\admin\index.php(160): Front->dispatch() 
#7 {main} thrown in C:\OpenServer\domains\depotop\vendor\pear\cache_lite\Cache\Lite.php on line 568
```

Pear on my server, 7.4 php version

```
# pear list
INSTALLED PACKAGES, CHANNEL PEAR.PHP.NET:
=========================================
PACKAGE          VERSION STATE
Archive_Tar      1.4.9   stable
Console_Getopt   1.4.3   stable
PEAR             1.10.12 stable
Structures_Graph 1.1.1   stable
XML_Util         1.4.5   stable
```

Why "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PEAR' not found in", how i can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs beacuse the file `PEAR.php` is not found in the given directory. You just include this file. Have you checked, if the file `PEAR.php` is really in the given path you use with `include_once('Pear.php')`?

The solution to your problem: Just give the right path to the include function.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. What path to pear.php needed?

Comment: I don 't know the path to your pear.php file. Have you read the PEAR documentation under https://pear.php.net/manual/en/? You have to add the path to your environment.